# Do Proguard keepnames do not obfuscate the application

Tags: java, android

I want to ask a noob question.

Does this proguard config not obfuscate my files or obfuscate all my java classes excluding only the name of classes?

Here the line:

```
-keepnames class ** { *; }
```

I want to build a release of my application and upload it to the public, is this line a problem to my application ? Does this line let others perform reverse engineering on my app easily ?

My app can be generated only using this line.

Thank you.

**PROGUARD SETTINGS**

```
-keepattributes Signature
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from     TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keepnames class org.apache.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.http.** {*;}    
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe

-keepnames class ** { *; }

-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep interface com.android.volley.** { *; }


-keep class com.sun.** {*;}
```

Comment: Slightly more easily, yes.  Not that proguard is all that much of a deterrent.  The truth is, nobody is interested in 99.9% of your app, even if you're a big name.  Spending a lot of time worrying about it is just a waste of time, and they'll get what they want anyway.  Spend your effort on making your app actually secure instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already spent my time on securing my app, but now i want offer a minimum protection for it obfuscating the code, and want know if my app obfuscated using this line or is same as generating it without proguard.

Comment: Somewhere in between.  It will prevent some things from being obfuscated (class names).  If this is required to make your app run, you're probably using reflection somewhere to create classes, which is something proguard can break.

Comment: I am not worried about class name, but the content of the classes, want them to be obfuscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-keepnames` stops ProGuard from changing the specified class and method names if they haven't been removed in the shrinking phase (`-keepnames` is short for `-keep,allowshrinking`)

So yes, if someone tries to decompile your app they can see the original names instead of the obfuscated gibberish

Comment: I am not worried about the original name but about the code contained in the class name, i want know if the code obfuscated or like class name not.

Comment: ProGuard only simplifies the code, the logic remains unchanged. Adding `-keepnames` will only make it easier to understand

Comment: I mean what about the code of the class it self ? will remain same ?

Comment: Depending on your ProGuard settings, it can be optimized and shrinked

Comment: I update my question with proguard settings, please take a look please.